# PHP combine $this variable

Tags: php

How to combine two variables to obtain / create new variable?

```
public $show_diary = 'my';

private my_diary(){
  return 1;
}

public view_diary(){
 return ${"this->"}.$this->show_diary.{"_diary()"}; // 1
 return $this->.{"$this->show_diary"}._diary() // 2
}
```

both return nothing.

Comment: In theory this should work: `return $this -> { $this -> show_diary . '_diary'} ();` Also see this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call

Comment: This is horrible to maintain and read, you should consider cleaner solutions. Anyway try this: `return $this->{$this->show_diary.'_diary'}()`

Comment: not sure what exactly you trying to do. Define your desire output with input.

Comment: This is so wrong. Don't try to build function calls dynamically.

Comment: I think he is trying to implement polymorphism in a wrong way.

Comment: you're posting syntax errors that should make your eyes bleed: `public view_diary()` should be `public function view_diary()`... `function` is _not optional!_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class should be like following:

```
class Test
{
    public $show_diary;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->show_diary = "my";
    }
    private function my_diary(){
      return 707;
    }

    public function view_diary(){
        echo $this->{$this->show_diary."_diary"}(); // 707
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It almost looks from your question like you are asking about how to turn simple variables into objects and then how to have one object contain another one. I could be way off, but I hope not:

So, first off, what is the differnce between an object and a simple variable? An object is really a collection of (generally) at least one property, which is sort of like a variable within it, and very often functions which do things to the properties of the object. Basically an object is like a complex variable.

In PHP, we need to first declare the strucutre of the object, this is done via a class statement, where we basicaly put the skeleton of what the object will be into place. This is done by the `class` statement. However, at this point, it hasn't actually been created, it is just like a plan for it when it is created later.

The creation is done via a command like:

```
 $someVariable= new diary();
```

This executes so create a new variable, and lays it out with the structure, properties and functions defined in the `class` statement.

From then on, you can access various properties or call functions within it.

```
class show_diary
{
    public $owner;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->owner='My';
    }
}

class view_diary
{
    public $owner;
    public $foo;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->foo='bar';
        $this->owner=new show_diary();
    }
}

$diary= new view_diary();
print_r($diary);
```

The code gives us two classes. One of the classes has an instance of the other class within it.

I have used constructors, which are a special type of function that is executed each time we create a new instance of a class - basically each time we declare a variable of that type, the `__construct` function is called.

When the `$diary= new view_diary();` code is called, it creates an instance of the `view_diary` class, and in doing so, the first thing it does is assigns it's own `foo` property to have the value 'bar' in it. Then, it sets it's `owner` property to be an instance of `show_diary` which in turn then kicks off the `__construct` function within the new instance. That in turn assigns the `owner` property of the child item to have the value 'My'.

If you want to access single properties of the object, you can do so by the following syntax:

```
echo $diary->foo;
```

To access a property of an object inside the object, you simply add more arrows:

```
echo $diary->owner->owner;
```

Comment: @tonoslfx I made a few additions pretty much the time this comment came through explaining in a bunch more detail what is going on if you care to read.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
$diary = $this->show_diary . '_diary';
return $this->$diary();
```