# difference between $object->item or $object['item']

Tags: php, object, notation

When I uses objects in webapplications, sometimes I have to use $object->item, and sometimes I have to use: $object['item'].
But what's the difference between both notations? When do I need the first notation, and when do I need the other notation?

Comment: So, in second case you are not using objects

Answer (score 0):

One is referencing an object:

```
echo $object->item;
```

In this case, you are echo'ing the property called 'item' within the object.

while the other is referencing an array:

```
echo $object['item'];
```

while in this case you are echo'ing the element with an associative index called 'item'.

I just wrote a [half decent explanation of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18696459/php-combine-this-variable/18696611#18696611) in another question which might be worth reading if you aren't sure about them (I really dislike to copy and paste answers).